# SQL INTO giving error as INTO table - undefined

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to copy 1 table selected columns INTO 2nd table selected columns, using this:

```
$sql = "SELECT (p.col1, p.col2)
INTO tblColors(b1,b2)
FROM tblPuppies as p
WHERE p.col3=1
";
```

But its giving me error : Undefined variable tblColors.
Strange to me. Any guesses plz, where m going wrong ??
Thanks tons in Advance.

Comment: Are you trying to copy data from one table to another?

Comment: And next time try to read manual first: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html which shows what is correct syntax for INSERT SELECT queries

Comment: @nospor INSERT INTO tblColors (b1, b2)
SELECT (col1, col2)  FROM tblPuppies WHERE b3 = 1. This I tried already. It gives me ERROR : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: In documetnation there is no () in SELECT ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
INSERT INTO tblColors (b1, b2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tblPuppies WHERE b3 = 1
```

Comment: INSERT INTO tblColors (b1, b2)
SELECT (col1, col2)  FROM tblPuppies WHERE b3 = 1. This I tried already. It gives me ERROR : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the select part. Use the exact query I posted

Comment: Oh Thanks..It was that PARENTHESES :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    INSERT INTO destination_table ( 
      Field_1, 
      Field_2, 
      Field_3) 
SELECT Field_1, 
      Field_2, 
      Field_3 
      FROM source_table;
```

Comment: If you use `SELECT`, then no need of `VALUES` with brackets `(`. It will throw error

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect SQL for doing this. The syntax you used works for T-SQL (or MS-SQL). But you are working on MySQL which has different syntax. You have update the statement as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblColors (b1, b2)
SELECT p.col1, p.col2 FROM tblPuppies AS p WHERE b3 = 1";
```